# Caching WCF ChannelFactory or client proxy in ASP.NET on Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, session, azure

As the question says. At the moment we're caching the WCF client proxy (ChannelFactory to be precise) to our services per session. This works fine. But now we've moved to Azure, and there are multiple instances (of session). I got AppFabric session state working now. So the session is provided by Azure, but now the problem is with caching of the channel factory. Because the factory is not [Serializable] and therefore it seems cannot be stored in the Session[]. What are the options? Should the channel be recreated every time the WCF service method is being called?

[ 1. previous working state; 2. newly attempted solution; 3. fall-back option ]

1. WCF Client -> ASP.NET -> Session cached factory -> Channel -> WCF Service
2. WCF Client -> ASP.NET -> Cannot store factory! -> Channel -> Azure role WCF Service
3. WCF Client -> ASP.NET -> New channel each call -> Azure role WCF Service

**Update**: We've established, that it won't be possible to cache (share) the ChannelFactory. So the question remains, how can I share the credentials (UserNameCredentials) which are therefore not being shared now, and somehow have to be distributed across the split instances. The obvious option is to store the encrypted credentials in a cache? Is it a good idea? Is there any other way to do it?

This continues as a new question: [How to share WCF client credentials...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324089/how-to-share-wcf-client-credentials-in-asp-net-amongst-role-instances-in-azure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cache the ChannelFactory, you are going to need to have one per session per azure role instance. You are correct that CacheFactories should not be shared across sessions as they may be supporting different users.

As you've rightly said, a CacheFactory is not serializable, so you're not going to be able to put it into the distributed cache.

Half the reason to cache it is to avoid the set-up time for the CacheFactory (may be many 10's of milliseconds). Serializing it into and out of the cache may be even longer than that as the CacheFactory is fairly large in size.

Comment: Thank you for a fast response. I agree, but where to store the credentials then? They're stored in a ChannelFactory, now that it's split into multiple instances. Not really a problem on it's own except for probably a tiny overhead. Should I somehow encrypt the credentials to serializable structure and store them in a session variable in Azure, and share that? Is that secure (being on Azure servers)? What's the best approach?

Comment: @SmartK8. Is it a problem if you have a copy of the credentials stored  per instance? I don't think you need to put them in your distributed cache as it's not essential that they're shared between instances no?

Comment: @SmartK8. You do have a different use case to me when I was sharing channelFactories though. In my situation, I was not using windows auth, so didn't need to have a channelFactory per session (as such). What I did was to create a static dictionary containing a ChannelFactory per service interface - as I was trying to avoid the setup cost per call of instantiating a channelFactory to allow me to  create my channel.

Comment: Well the problem is I don't have them on the other instance, and therefore the service will fail security check. So now it looks like so, that I sign in, and when I refresh the page it either loads correctly, or throws an exception depending on which instance provides it (kind of funny to be honest).

Comment: I had it similar so far. Just a dictionary singleton per interface stored in session (user). The credentials were provided on sign-in. So up until the that it is a similar scenario. Now the difference is the need for credentials.

Comment: Ok. I don't have an answer for you on this one I'm afraid. I've +1'd your question so hopefully you'll get some interest. Mightn't be a bad idea to mention about caching the credentials in the question also.

Comment: I've +1'd your answer, because it is a half of it. I'll wait if someone will offer the solution for credentials. Otherwise I'll mark it as a answer.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: OK. I'll close this question, and rephrase it as a new one. Because I think you basically answered the question. The new problem with credentials arose later.