# How to share WCF client credentials in ASP.NET amongst role instances in Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, security, azure

This problem is a continuation of the caching of ChannelFactory in a session problem here:

[Caching WCF ChannelFactory or client proxy in ASP.NET on Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322061/caching-wcf-channelfactory-or-client-proxy-in-asp-net-on-azure)

How can I share the credentials (UserNameCredentials) which are therefore not being shared now, and somehow have to be distributed across the split instances of WCF clients. The obvious option is to store the encrypted credentials in a cache? Is it a good idea? Is there any other way to do it?